# Is it safe to map a key to a custom escape sequence in iTerm?

Tags: vim, terminal

There are some keys I use in MacVim that terminal Vim doesn't recognize. For example, Ctrl-Enter, Shift-Enter, Ctrl-Space, Shift-Space, Ctrl-Backspace.

I'm using iTerm2, which lets you map keyboard shortcuts to send escape sequences. It seems like I could use this to make my desired key mappings work in the terminal. Something like,

iTerm2

```
Ctrl-Space: Send ^[[123;456ABC
```

Vim

```
set <F13>=^[[123;456ABC
map <F13> <S-Space>

noremap <S-Space> mzO<Esc>j`z
```

I'm not sure this will work, but I'm also wondering what I should be aware of before I start creating custom escape sequences willy-nilly. It seems like it could cause problems...

Comment: You should use universally mappable keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between these 2 pages (below) I figured it out:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/iterm2-discuss/VEiCSc5LCIs
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim

You stay "safe" by using the key codes for unused Function keys. In iTerm2, I created "keyboard shortcuts" that map the desired key-combos to the [escape sequences](http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/term-function-keys.html) for Function keys F13 through F16. Then, in my vimrc, I set Vim's keycodes appropriately, mapped the desired key-combos to the right Function keys, then mapped the same key-combos to whatever I want. I'm not sure I fully understand the direction things are flowing in, but it all gets linked up and works. Here's the relevant portion of my vimrc:

```
" use some unused function key codes to
" make special key combos work in terminal
set  <F13>=O2P
map  <F13> <C-CR>
map! <F13> <C-CR>

set  <F14>=O2Q
map  <F14> <S-CR>
map! <F14> <S-CR>

set  <F15>=O2R
map  <F15> <C-Space>
map! <F15> <C-Space>

set  <F16>=O2S
map  <F16> <S-Space>
map! <F16> <S-Space>

" open above / below current line
inoremap <S-CR> <C-O>O
inoremap <C-CR> <C-O>o

" insert above / below current line
noremap <S-Space> mzO<Esc>j`z
noremap <C-Space> mzo<Esc>k`z
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my `<Ctrl-Tab>` hotkey which worked in MacVim and also in console vim in iTerm2, but not when ssh'd in to another machine from iTerm. My solution was to modify iTerm's existing Key Binding for `<Ctrl-Tab>` (which I never used) to Send Escape Sequence `[17~` (the escape sequence for `<F6>` -- another thing I never used -- as found in the table linked by @ivan). In my .vimrc, I added a mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F6> :echo "success!"<CR>
```